# How Can I Define a Function Whose Parameters Change According to Input File?

Tags: python, function

I  have a CBR function which takes 4 parameters like
CBR (w1,w2,w3,w4,x_train,y_train)
w1 to wn changes according to the input file. w1 to wn are weights of independent parameters. Thus, according to the input file and the size of the input parameters, w1 to wn changes (N size of input parameters).
How can I define such a function?
Could you give me an example?
Thanks

Comment: You can pass them as a list of variables

Comment: you should consider using *args in python function. for more information see this link https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a variable number of arguments you can use

```
def CBR(x_train, y_train, *args):
   ...
```

The special syntax `*args` is used to pass a variable number of arguments to a function.

The syntax is to use the symbol `*` to take in a variable number of arguments; by convention, it is often used with the word `args` but you can use `w` if you prefer.